# how to solve sql problem by accessing information from multiple tables to get end result

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm writing some queries for homework this week and I am stuck with this one.
I need to gather information from multiple tables without using join

- A list showing each product requested on each client stock request. Show
  client name, product number and quantity requested, sorted by client name and then
  product number.

my current code shows an output but dosent give the right results. it prints the contents of table 5 times instead of once as per the problem.

```
SELECT CLIENT.clientName, REQUEST_LIST.productNum, REQUEST_LIST.qtyRequested
FROM CLIENT, REQUEST_LIST 
WHERE CLIENT.clientNum IN (
    SELECT clientNum
    FROM STOCK_REQUEST)
    AND REQUEST_LIST.requestNum IN (
        SELECT requestNum
        FROM STOCK_REQUEST)
ORDER BY CLIENT.clientName , REQUEST_LIST.productNum
```

here are the tables:

```
(stock request) 
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2020-12-10',1);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2020-05-04',2);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2021-07-06',3);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2021-07-08',4);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2022-02-07',5);


(request list) 
INSERT INTO Request_List (requestNum, productNum, qtyRequested)
    VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Request_List (requestNum, productNum, qtyRequested)
    VALUES (2,2,2);
INSERT INTO Request_List (requestNum, productNum, qtyRequested)
    VALUES (3,3,3);
INSERT INTO Request_List (requestNum, productNum, qtyRequested)
    VALUES (4,4,4);
INSERT INTO Request_List (requestNum, productNum, qtyRequested)
    VALUES (5,5,5);

(client) 
INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
    VALUES ('Mike');
INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
    VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
    VALUES ('Sally');
INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
    VALUES ('Margret');
INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
    VALUES ('Max');
```

any help would be appreciated.

expected output : ( not actual numbers )

```
client number |   product number | quantity requested

John Smith.        1.                3


Margret Thatcher.    3.                7

Max Payne.          6.                1

Mike Costello.      2.                1

Sally Barbarella.    4.               4
```

Comment: Could you provide your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: Would be much easier if you show the complete `INSERT`-statements as your SQL-statement refers to columns not shown within the `INSERT-statements.

Comment: For your expected output, please refer to your given example so that we know what results you really want, or kindly change your insert examples and match it with your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not need  to use subqueries to get `clien_num` and `request_num` values from `stock_request` table. Just use conditions in `where` clause of query. Row set is limited by `stock_request` records, row values allows to get appopriate values from `client` and `request_list` tables.

Second, i suggest you not to use casesensitive table and column names, it may lead errors by typos.

Finaly, your query would be like this

```
SELECT 
    client.client_name, 
    request_list.product_num, 
    request_list.qty_requested
FROM client, request_list, stock_request 
WHERE client.client_num = stock_request.client_num AND stock_request.request_num = request_list.request_num
ORDER BY client.client_name , request_list.product_num
```

Check fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nFQ3s1GGEELCMoPBvPYwyk/1